# Change sequencer image strip filename through python

Tags: python, scripting, video-sequence-editor, image

i'm trying to access and change the filename of image strips in the sequencer for a little addon i'm developping, but i'm stuck with invalid syntax, i think, and i can't find the correct way to put that... Here's what i've got so far :

```
import bpy


for scene in bpy.data.scenes: 

    if scene.sequence_editor is not None:

        strip = scene.sequence_editor.sequences_all

        if strip is not None:
            for obj in strip:
                if obj.type == 'IMAGE':

                    obj.elements.Sequence_Element.filename="ok"
```

But last line doesn't work... Does anyone have an idea about that ? Or know the correct way ? Thank you very much !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Sequencer Strip has a `name` property, which is assigned by the user in Blender. It also has an `SequenceElement` list which contains all "file" elements of that strip. (Especially with image sequences you have multiple files.) We need to access the `SequenceElement`s `filename` property. Image strips only have a single `SequenceElement` which will be indiced with `0`.

The correct code is:

```
import bpy

for scene in bpy.data.scenes: 
    if scene.sequence_editor is not None:
        strip = scene.sequence_editor.sequences_all
        if strip is not None:
            for obj in strip:
                if obj.type == 'IMAGE':
                    obj.name = "ok"
                    obj.elements[0].filename = "ok.png"
```

Comment: perfect thanks you @Leander !  works like a charm ! i was aware of the name attribute, but i want to let it unchanged (because it's up to user to rename its strips) but i didn't know the good way to get to the elements attribute ! perfect !